# Running Subtotals in Microsoft Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I am using Microsoft Access 2016 and there is table where I want to count each occurrence of a value in a column grouping by another column. Below is sample data from the table:

| ID | Date | Weekday | Trip_ID | Day | Location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 9/11/2022 | Mon | TI06091122 | 1 | Florida |
| 2 | 9/12/2022 | Tue | TI06091122 | 2 | Travel Day |
| 3 | 9/13/2022 | Wed | TI06091122 | 3 | Georgia |
| 4 | 9/14/2022 | Thu | TI06091122 | 4 | South Carolina |
| 5 | 9/15/2022 | Fri | TI06091122 | 5 | North Carolina |
| 6 | 9/16/2022 | Sat | TI06091122 | 6 | Travel Day |
| 7 | 9/17/2022 | Sun | TI06091122 | 7 | Florida |
| 8 | 9/18/2022 | Mon | TI06091822 | 1 | Florida |
| 9 | 9/19/2022 | Tue | TI06091822 | 2 | Travel Day |
| 10 | 9/20/2022 | Wed | TI06091822 | 3 | Travel Day |
| 11 | 9/21/2022 | Thu | TI06091822 | 4 | Travel Day |
| 12 | 9/22/2022 | Fri | TI06091822 | 5 | Colorado |
| 13 | 9/23/2022 | Sat | TI06091822 | 6 | California |
| 14 | 9/24/2022 | Sun | TI06091822 | 7 | Florida |

I want to group the data by `Trip_ID` and then do a rolling count for each `Location`. The result I am aiming for is this:

| Trip_ID | Location | RunningCount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| TI06091122 | Florida | 1 |
| TI06091122 | Travel Day | 1 |
| TI06091122 | Georgia | 1 |
| TI06091122 | South Carolina | 1 |
| TI06091122 | North Carolina | 1 |
| TI06091122 | Travel Day | 2 |
| TI06091122 | Florida | 2 |
| TI06091822 | Florida | 1 |
| TI06091822 | Travel Day | 1 |
| TI06091822 | Travel Day | 2 |
| TI06091822 | Travel Day | 3 |
| TI06091822 | Colorado | 1 |
| TI06091822 | California | 1 |
| TI06091822 | New Mexico | 1 |
| TI06091822 | Florida | 2 |

I am able to do a rolling total for the whole table by adding a temporary column equal to 1, and then using `DSUM` on that column.

```sql
DSUM("Temp_Col","Table", "ID<=" & ID) As RunningCount
```

I believe if I do some sort of subquery per `Trip_ID` that would do the `DSUM` I would get what I am looking for, but am unable to determine how to set it up.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: @HansUp that was a typo, I corrected it. Thanks for seeing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to include `Trip_id` and `Location` references in your `DSum()` criteria in order to get the count for each combination of those two fields.  However, since you're actually after a *count*, use [DCount()](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dcount-function-f6b5d78b-ad0b-4e42-be7a-11a64acbf3d3) instead of *"... adding a temporary column equal to 1, and then using DSUM on that column"*.

Here is a tested example with a `DCount()` expression for that derived column:

```sql
SELECT
    hp.Trip_ID,
    hp.Location,
    DCount(
        "*",
        "tblHuskypride",
        "Trip_ID='" & hp.Trip_id & "' AND Location='" & hp.Location & "' AND ID<=" & hp.ID
        ) AS RunningCount
FROM tblHuskypride AS hp
ORDER BY hp.Date;
```

(Notice I renamed my copy of the table to *"tblHuskypride"*.)

Although that gives you what I think you want, I don't like all the quotes it requires.  So I would prefer to use a correlated subquery as in the following example.

```sql
SELECT
    hp.Trip_ID,
    hp.Location,
    (
        SELECT Count(*)
        FROM tblHuskypride AS hp2
        WHERE
                hp2.Trip_ID=hp.Trip_ID 
            AND hp2.Location=hp.Location
            AND hp2.Date<=hp.Date
    ) AS RunningCount
FROM tblHuskypride AS hp
ORDER BY hp.Date;
```

Notice I chose to use the `Date` field instead of `ID` for the counting.  If that's not satisfactory, swap `ID` for `Date`. Here is the output from that query tested with your sample data:

| Trip_ID | Location | RunningCount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| TI06091122 | Florida | 1 |
| TI06091122 | Travel Day | 1 |
| TI06091122 | Georgia | 1 |
| TI06091122 | South Carolina | 1 |
| TI06091122 | North Carolina | 1 |
| TI06091122 | Travel Day | 2 |
| TI06091122 | Florida | 2 |
| TI06091822 | Florida | 1 |
| TI06091822 | Travel Day | 1 |
| TI06091822 | Travel Day | 2 |
| TI06091822 | Travel Day | 3 |
| TI06091822 | Colorado | 1 |
| TI06091822 | California | 1 |
| TI06091822 | Florida | 2 |

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I opted for the correlated subquery. The RunningCount I was getting was in reverse order, so I changed it to

`hp2.Date>=hp.Date`